# Magento sometimes loading wrong CSS file

Tags: theme, css

I am using a custom theme for my Magento store with a bunch of custom modules. Everything works correctly 99% of the time, but I notice occasionally in the Server logs that Magento is looking in the wrong place for my CSS file, as if the theme isn't loaded. But when I visit the accused URL, it loads fine.

Log Examples:

```
[Sun Nov 16 15:18:13 2014] [error] File does not exist: (root)/httpdocs/skin/frontend/base/default/css/suggest.css, referer: http://www.comstarsupply.com/suggest/cart/add/product/7413
[Sun Nov 16 16:07:09 2014] [error] File does not exist: (root)/skin/frontend/base/default/css/magicmile.css
```

You can visit those URLs and see that everything loads correctly, so I'm not sure how this can be happening. Any thoughts on where I could start to track down the problem?

Comment: Maybe you have configured design exceptions in the design configuration and these log records are triggered by mobile users visiting your site?

Comment: Oh!, you're right... that's what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added my comment as an answer so you can accept it please.

Maybe you have configured design exceptions in the design configuration and these log records are triggered by mobile users visiting your site?

Comment: Thanks; can't believe I didn't think of this myself!

Comment: I spent a long time figuring that out on a site, too.